# Regex works in Grep but not vim

Tags: regex, linux, vim, grep

I have a file of this format, problem.txt:

```
StarBonds

↯ | 356 Positions | Gain: H$59,834,200 (15.26%)
Security    Shares  &   Paid    Current     Today   ▲   Value   Gain / Loss     ±
AANDE   20,000  !|!     H$26.35     H$29.84     H$0.08      H$596,800   H$69,800    13%
ABASS   20,000  !|!     H$51.68     H$51.29     -H$0.27         H$1,025,800     -H$7,800    -0%
ABRAG   20,000  !|!     H$39.65     H$44.98     -H$0.13     ▼   H$899,600   H$106,600   13%
ABRES   20,000  !|!     H$49.62     H$45.26     -H$0.40         H$1,079,600     H$87,200    8%
```

I want to remove all lines that do not start with the 2-5 Character, All capital letter identifier.

On the command line with grep, it shows me only those lines and not the 'junk lines' (First four at top of example above).  i.e.  The result I want.
 $ grep  '^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]+' problem.txt

```
AANDE   20,000  !|!     H$26.35     H$29.84     H$0.08      H$596,800   H$69,800    13%     
ABASS   20,000  !|!     H$51.68     H$51.29     -H$0.27         H$1,025,800     -H$7,800    -0%     
ABRAG   20,000  !|!     H$39.65     H$44.98     -H$0.13     ▼   H$899,600   H$106,600   13%     
ABRES   20,000  !|!     H$49.62     H$45.26     -H$0.40         H$1,079,600     H$87,200    8%
```

In vim, with the same regex, it doesn't find it, even when I remove the beginning of line marker:

```
:%s/^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]+
%s/E486: Pattern not found: [A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]+
```

When I try removing digits, I get the same error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: [A-Z][A-Z]+
```

The goal is to change the %s// to %g//d once I can get vim to find the regex.

Using vim on Debian Jessie, grep from same.

Vim is default install, I'm not sure if there's a flag that needs to be set, other searches haven't been an issue in the past.

Comment: You have to escape the `+` in vim, as in `\+`.

Comment: Thank you.  I missed the "Magic" mode for regex in vim and the escapes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In vim `+` must be escaped, therefore you can keep the specified lines with:

```
:%g!/^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]\+/d
```

If you only wish to match lines starting with 2 to 5 character sequences you could instead use:

```
:%g!/^[A-Z0-9]\{2,5\}/d
```